# Dialogflow - Dynamic text response

Tags: dialogflow-es

How can I set dynamic args in Text response?
not from user phrases

I have a case:

bot says: "Do you find a work?"

user says: "Yes"

Text response:

bot says: "I can offer you vacancy {random vacancy}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with a default text response, in fact, you need to enable webhook call for that intent in the fulfillment section. I'll show you how my intent looks like.
[image]

Here you have the webhook code:

```js
'use strict';
const http = require('http');


const request2 = require('request');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = (req, res) => {
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  
  let action = req.body.queryResult['intent']['displayName'];
  switch(action){
    case "work":
        // Get the city from a database
        let city="Randomcity";
        // Get the job from a database
        let job="randomjob";
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'fulfillmentText': "I can offer you this fantastic job in "+city+" city, doing "+job}));
               
          
    break;
    
    //Add more cases if you have more intents
    }
    
  
    
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases :
1. If you want to return random arguments, then you can simply set all possible arguments in the responses and DialogFlow will randomly select a response a send it to user.

[image]

2. If the arguments are based on some criteria, then you need to enable webhook and you need to return the response from the webhook. This is the recommended option. And [this is how fulfillment works](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works).

Hope it helps.